# assembly - Splitting 8-digit hex value into n digits?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86, hex, cpu-registers

For example, a user inputs `01010101`, and the program splits it into `01 01 01 01` to read as separate values assigned to a specific constant.

I'm aware that shifts/pulling values out of a 32-bit register and masking needs to occur, though I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Have you considered reading an instruction set reference to find out how to do shifting and masking on x86?

Comment: @FUZxxl I've looked at my professor's reference guide, but it's vague so I don't understand it clearly. I also experimented with the SAR instruction. For example, inputting 20 (hex), using `sar( 1, ebx )`, then it prints 16 (decimal). So I don't understand where the other values are going, how to store them, etc.

Comment: hexadecimal 20 is the bit patter 100000. Deciaml 16 is hexadecimal 16 is the bit pattern 010000. Each bit is shifted to the right by one bit. What is the unclear part?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` to mask out bit and `SHR` to shift bit to right

```
MOV dl, 0b01010101
AND dl, 0b00000001 ;dl now equals 1
MOV al, 0b01010101
AND al, 0b00000100 ;al now equals 0b00000100 = 4
SHR al, 2 ;al now equals 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit operator "AND" to do this.

Assume now you store the original "01011100" in register AH and you want to split it into "01", "01", "11", "00" and store each of them in BH, BL, CH, CL.

You can do it like this:

```
MOV BH AH ;now the BH is 01011100 ,just like AH 
AND BH 0B11000000 ;since "a AND b" equals 1 only when both a and b equal 1 ,so the first two bit of AH will be the same as that of BH, and the other six bit will be 0 because one of the operand is 0 . In this way you can split it.
```

And you can do the rest in the same way :

```
MOV BL AH ;now the BL is 01011100 ,just like AH 
AND BL 0B00110000 ;now BL is 00010000

MOV CH AH ;now the CH is 01011100 ,just like AH 
AND CH 0B00001100 ;now the CH is 00001100

MOV CL AH ;now the CL is 01011100 ,just like AH 
AND CL 0B00000011 ;now the DH is 00000000
```